# Spring Security @PreAuthorize on controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to use the url (ant based) matching along with @PreAuthorize("permitAll") on some controllers i.e.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {
...

  @PreAuthorize("permitAll")
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String register() { ... }
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

I've also tried adding @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity to my MVC config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { ... }
```

But this has no effect

However I am still prompted to authenticate when hitting /register. If I add "/register" to the ant matchers it works i.e. .antMatchers("/", "/register").permitAll()

What am I missing here? It seems @PreAuthorize has no effect on my controllers

Comment: I should clarify that @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')") on a controller does work: non-admins will get a 403 error. The issue is specifically how to override the ant matcher with the @PreAuthorize annotation

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You cannot do that because ant matchers and `@PreAuthorize` work at different level.

The ant matchers works at *http* security level. Spring security filter looks at the request, and if it find that access should be denied, it does not even pass the request to the dispatcher servlet, and directly send a 403 error.

`PreAuthorize` work at *method* level. When a method is about to be called, an AOP proxy controls if the access should be allowed. So the 2 authorizations level are **chained**, instead of the second overriding the first.

Anyway, I strongly advice you **not** to use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` on a controller :

- it can easily be done with a simple ant matcher
- it forces you to allow proxying on a controller, either with class proxying instead of JDK proxying or by using interfaces for controllers

IMHO, `@PreAuthorize` is best suited at service level, because you can mix domain objects with user granted authorities to get fine grained authorizations.

Comment: Thanls Serge, The reason I was planning to use the annotations was to keep things simple and maintainable, at the moment I need to map "/register", "/register/" and "/register/*" in the security config and if I change the request mapping I need to change these also.